How to read entire section from Azure Key Vault?
I have an Azure Key Vault where I have kept my application secrets section wise using -- as follows



Secret Name
Value




Section--Secret1
Value1


Section--Secret2
Value2


Section--Secret3
Value3



So here if I represent this as JSON it will be as follows
{
 "Section": {
  "Secret1":"Value1",
  "Secret2":"Value2",
  "Secret3":"Value3",
 }
}

Here the problem that I am facing is when I read secrets from Key Vault using Configuration  I am not getting values. But when I read individual value I am getting it.
Like,
When I read Configuration["Section:Secret1"] I am getting value.
At the same time if I read Configuration["Section"] I am getting null.
Is there any way to read the entire section from Key Vault?
I have referred this. But its not providing details about how to read the entire section. Its difficult to read individual keys if the number of keys increase.

I created a key Vault and added secrets like below:

To retrieve entire section from Azure Key Vault, make use of below code:
using Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;

var kvUri = new Uri("https://rukkv3333.vault.azure.net/");
var client = new SecretClient(kvUri, new DefaultAzureCredential());

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.AddAzureKeyVault(client, new KeyVaultSecretManager());

var config = builder.Build();
var section = config.GetSection("Section").GetChildren();

foreach (var item in section)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {item.Value}");
}


As code authenticates with DefaultAzureCredential login to az like below:
az login



This is working as expected. Thanks @Rukmini

Glad to know that it worked:)
